# Pressure distribution on path area of a rolling rubber tire and its stress-strain diagram

Tags: rolling

A singular 2D circular rubber tire rolls with constant speed on solid plane non-deformable ground.

1. How can one be able to qualitatively draw the pressure distribution made by the tire on the contact area (in this case a line)?

At the ends of the "contact line" there is no compression so the pressure there must be zero.
As far as I know at the middle point of the line the pressure distribution does not peak, maybe through hysteresis an explanation could be found.

2. Does the stress-strain curve rise and dips slightly at the end of the Loading section of the tire (where the strain of the tire is max, AKA at the mid point of the contact line which would explain why peak pressure does not happen at max strain)?
3. Is the "strain"/compression of the tire measured radially exclusively, or do shear components also play a part in how the Pressure distribution of a rolling tire look like?

These questions are quite essential in my opinion to people that are enthusiastic in learning Vehicle Dynamics.

Comment: The contact patch of a real tire is roughly oval. The pressure distribution can be measured, or calculated in various ways. Typically the centroid of the force distribution is to the rear of the axle. This is widely discussed in vehicle dynamics books, and of course Dr Pacejka has made it his life's work.

Comment: What articles, books papers have you found so we don't waste our time duplicating stuff you have already?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a two D rubber tire standing still, it will be flattened at the contact line (surface if 3D), with stress distributed as strata of horizontal contour lines with curved-down ends, gradually curving more and radiating out in the rubber disk.
As the tire starts to roll, the contour lines immediately to the front of the contact line are compressed further and create a vibration shock that has its lucus near the front side of the tire.
If the tire has a small damping index, the vibrations are going to amplify and become chaotic.

If the viscosity of the tire is enough to dampen this vibration, the stress line under the tire will be as shown in the figure.

The reason for the negative stress at the back of the contact line is that the rubber material particles there have no vertical speed and have to be accelerated up to catch up with the rotation of the adjacent neighbor particles already turning.

This stress diagram radiates through the tire and can resonate depending on the stiffness and geometry of the tire, developing beats! The tire will then bounce. In real tires, this shows as dented cuppings!

.

[image: rubber tire]